# Raster classes not appearing in legend

Tags: r, raster

I created this raster `.tiff` file. It is available from [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1SnBmn4kZ3BxGdwtn_HnqbwrNHcyW7KXW/view?usp=sharing).

I had created the `countieslandcover.tiff` through this code:

`countieslandcover <- aggregate(landcover_countiesmap, fact = 3, fun = min, expand = F, na.rm = T)`

whereby `landcover_countiesmap` was the initial raster with 13988 rows and 16304 columns before downsampling . When I tried drawing this initial raster `landcover_countiesmap` with 'tmap` I got an error:

```
Warning in fetch(.x, ..., downsample = downsample) :
  with RasterIO defined, argument downsample is ignored
stars_proxy object shown at 16304 by 13998 cells.
Error: cannot allocate vector of size 870.6 Mb
Error during wrapup: cannot allocate vector of size 870.6 Mb
Error: no more error handlers available (recursive errors?); invoking 'abort' restart
```

This is when I decided to downsample the raster to `countieslandcover.tiff` using the `aggregate` function. Upon doing so, the raster was able to be drawn using `tmap`.  However, the issue is that my values do not appear distinctly on the legend. Instead of '1', '2', '3' and so on they appear as '1 to 2', '2 to 3' as in the image below.

[image: Legend values should appear distinctly, not in twos]

Here is the raster metadata for `countieslandcover.tiff`, the result of making it coarser using the `aggregate` function.

```
> class      : RasterLayer 
> dimensions : 4666, 5434, 25355044  (nrow, ncol, ncell)
> resolution : 0.0005555558, 0.0005555558  (x, y)
> extent     : 34.34335, 37.36224, -1.442097, 1.150127  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
> crs        : +proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs 
> source     : r_tmp_2022-04-19_212648_10928_21780.grd 
> names      : Kenya_Sentinel2_LULC2016 
> values     : 1, 10  (min, max)
```

Here is the code I used when drawing the raster with `tmap`

```
tm_shape(countieslandcover) + tm_raster(palette = terrain.colors(10, 0.7, rev = F), n= 10, legend.show = T, legend.is.portrait = T, colorNA = NULL) + 
  tm_layout(title = 'Landcover types of top 5 counties by population', legend.position = c('left', 'bottom'))
```

How can I make the `values` appear distinctively (like separated) on both the map and the legend? My `values` stands for landcover classes and will make sense if each appears standing on its own on the legend (ie. '1', '2' and so on) two landcovers can't exist on the same place.  I tried reproject the raster to a local datum, `+init=epsg:32737` and also played with the `tm_raster` arguments to no avail.

Answer (score 0):

Example categorical raster

```
library(terra)
set.seed(0)
r <- rast(nrows=10, ncols=10)
values(r) <- sample(3, ncell(r), replace=TRUE) - 1
cls <- c("forest", "water", "urban")
levels(x) <- cls
names(x) <- "land cover"
plot(x)
```

The standard way to aggregate this would be with the "modal" function

```
a <- aggregate(x, 2, "modal")
plot(a)
```

But you use the `min` function, which probably makes no sense anyway, and then you loose the levels

```
b <- aggregate(x, 2, "min")
plot(b)
```

But you could restore the categories with

```
levels(b) <- levels(x)
plot(b)
```

Comment: Hello @Robert Hijmans, I tried using the `modal` argument in the `aggregate` function but it still did not work. The levels appear merged as before. Furthermore, I used the `levels` function to force the categories of the initial raster `counties_landcover`  to a duplicate of my aggregated raster, called `countieslandcover_datum2` and tried to plot using tmap. Still the same. The values on legend are still merged (`1 to 2`, `3 to 4`) etc